# Reporting Services - header with blank spaces

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, rdlc

I got the problem that my RDLC-Report always repeats the whole header, if there is data or not, it always repeats the blank space.

I dont want to use a Rectangle instead of my header or something, is there a workaround with let this header-data in the header?

I dont want to have this blank spaces, i wanna see my body there.

Thanks in ancipiation
Alex

Comment: If you use a header, it will show on every page of the report.

Comment: were you able to find a solution or alternative to your header problem?  I think one of the hardest things with SSRS is trying to reproduce the layout of a form...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a group header...?  Hide the row(s) if there's no data for it, and that won't leave a space... set the header to repeat on each page.

Would that be an option?

I've done a few reports that required a footer but some of the stuff in there was only needed on the last page but I didn't want that huge white space in the footer area when the visibility was set to hide for all the pages but the last one... A group footer didn't work for me because I needed certain things at the very bottom of every page (like a form) and you can't access the globals from in the body of the report to toggle visibility... Ultimately I had to setting for that stuff I wanted on the last page to be at the end of the data, meaning it might be in the middle of the last page.... But I positioned my main tablix inside a big rectangle that's is equal to the whole page length - margin size - header length - footer length - (that rectangle I want on the last page).length so that if there is only one row of data, that last page item isn't directly below it but actually right above the footer where it should be.  However, if the data is more than a page, that rectangle is just at the end of the data, which is an okay compromise.

Comment: And there's always something to group by, it doesn't have to be a column on your report or anything, just the basis of the outermost group.  You could even add select 'taco' as groupOnMe to your main body query and group on that..... try the group header idea, it's the closest answer I can think of....... ORRRR =>  Subreport?  That is 1px high, set to canGrow, but that can't be in a header... It can be a group header, though, I believe.  And hide the row, if there's no data?